# Is there any risk of using WCF RIA Services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I’ve just learned from books that we can avoid lots of tedious asynchronous callback code in silverlight project using WCF RIA Services. I want try to refactor our existing project using WCF RIA Services for cleaner code.
Is there anyone who have practical experience on WCF RIA Services can tell me is it wise to adopt it on silverlight project? Is there any reliability or performance issue about WCF RIA Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with RIA Services your calls will have to follow the async pattern. There is no way around it with Silverlight. RIA services are just a little more comfortable because you will be spared the hassle of updating Sevice References etc.